# How to properly store BeautifulSoup objects for later use

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Lately, I've been trying to store the source code of some pages so I can later scrap what I need from them without having to worry about internet or possible anti-scraping measures. My first approach was to save the `bs.prettify` object of each link into a column of the same DataFrame. After a while, I realized I can't navigate the parse tree on those objects (for example, accessing `bs.h1`). So, I wanted to know if there's a way to turn the string from the `bs.prettify` object into a navigable BeautifulSoup object or if there's a better way than storing into a DataFrame the source code for later use?

Comment: I usually store the HTML itself completely in a txt or html format if I have to use it later again.

Comment: And then I can run BeautifulSoup() over that string?

Comment: Yes, using the relevant parser :)

Comment: Nice! that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !